# My ps1 file do not work due to PowerShell Constrained Language. Can I replace it with a visual studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

Firstly, I am not a professional coder.  I am working for finance unit of an international firm, responsible of preparing financials etc. for regulatory bodies etc.
I have designed a PowerShell solution which looks for specific files in network drive and if it finds the files, sends them via outlook e-mail to my team members.  But if it does not find the files, sends the e-mail with a warning text etc.
This was working fine until our IT admins applied a system-wide PowerShell Constrained Language mode.  This mode prevents running of outlook-related e-mail automation commands in ps1 file and making my solution useless.

My 1st question is about bypassing this mode and the powershell itself.  Can I design a similar solution in visual studio ? If so what kind of project should I work on, in which language?

My 2nd question is about insisting on my current solution.  I can understand IT admins in my organization putting PowerShell Constrained Language mode into use, as there are risks of viruses and attacks with bad intentions.  Is there any other way which eliminates these risks while keeping my solution still working.

p.s. I have excel vba codes of the same solution but I do not want to use it as it interrupts my work while I was doing something in excel (excel is nearly always open&busy in my PC).

Comment: ask your admin people to allow you an account that is NOT constrained.

Comment: Tried it.  But they said everyone in the organization -including IT guys- is running the same version of PS with constrained Language mode.

Comment: ah! that means some one totally misunderstands security. [*grin*] you are stuck. if you can't run powershell the way it is intended to be run - as MS defaults it on their servers - then you won't be able to use WMI, WScript, VBScript, or any other language. it seems you are stuck with "security theater" and will have to use VBA. you have my condolences ... [*sigh ...*]

Comment: Like @Lee_Daily said, you'll need to head to the management to sort this out. "Even code written in c# will no longer execute." as per the documentation from MS. "The Add-Type cmdlet can load signed assemblies, but it cannot load arbitrary C# code or Win32 APIs." Excerpt from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_modes?view=powershell-7

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about IT policy and more suitable at The Workplace.

Comment: Can't you ask your company to just sign your script with a certificate? In a proper setup with constrained language mode signed scripts should function.

Comment: thank you all for assistance.  @bluuf I am updating the folder names in PS1 script everyday, so I guess process of PS1 file signing will need to be done everyday.  Therefore this does not fit to my case.

Comment: But if there is an option like a "signed folder" or something which makes all scripts in that folder automatically signed and overcome constrained language.

Comment: If you're updating (hardcoded) folder names in scripts on a daily base you have a problem in your process. Build your scripts so they can read from an inputfile or something and you should be set (since that means your scripts rarely change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment thread contributors suggested, the way to solve this kind of issue is to talk to the management. Do not try to work around the technical safeguards, although [it would be easy](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-constrained-language-mode/) to do so. If you do, keep in mind that intentional violation of a security policy might be a fireable offence.

When dealing with your boss, a solution-oriented approach is often useful. Don't just complain about the policy, offer a solution. Write up max two pages memo explaining the issue. Include an estimate how much manual routine work you have to do, if they are error-prone, what are the effects of an human error and what more productive things you could do meanwhile. Even if it's five minutes a day, sum it up to yearly level.

The important thing is that you propose solutions. You could ask IT if they have any ideas. For example, IT could sign the script. They could take over the whole thing, so you wouldn't need to worry about running it anymore. Maybe an existing monitoring system could watch the files for you. Explore the options.

Don't overdo the memo, less your boss is going to wonder how many hours you've used to write a memo instead of, you know, doing your actual work. See [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) for further advice.